# XCTestCase setUp once with async operation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm trying to write some unit tests for an iOS client that consumes a web service API. I want to use the actual service and not mock data.

Before all the tests can run I need to get a token to authenticate the user with.
I'm trying to use the class `setUp` method in order to do that - but I'm not sure how to wait for the token to arrive before I continue with the rest of the tests (since all network calls are async).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an function that waits for the token using a dummy(no validation inside) `assync` test like this:

```
 func waitforToken(){
    let dummyExpectation = expectationWithDescription("Expect to get my token")
    ... call web service

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(20, handler: { error in
         XCTAssertNil(error, "Error")
    })
}
//on the web service Callback fulfill the expectation
func webServiceCallback(expectation:expectationWithDescription, ...)  {
   ...
   expectation.fulfill()
}
```

Then just call it on the start of each test. Probably won't work if you call inside `setUp`, but i can be wrong.